# SQL Server varchar values retrieved incorrectly when your database and client have different codepages

Tags: delphi, sql-server-2017, firedac, delphi-10.4-sydney

I have an SQL Server database with plenty of iso_1 (iso8859-1) columns that are retrieved incorrectly on a Windows desktop with utf-8 codepage (65001) while they are retrieved fine on Windows desktops with Windows-1252 (iso8819-1) codepage.

> Error: [FireDAC][DatS]-32. Variable length column [nom] overflow. Value length - [51], column maximum length - [50]

This is due because characters like Ñ are retrieved incorrectly coded as a couple of characters.

SQL Server Management Studio retrieves those columns correctly, so I guess the problem is configuring the FireDAC connection of my application, but I can't see anywhere a charset property to indicate the codepage of the original data.

How do you indicate the transcode needed on a FireDAC connection when the codepage is different in the database and the desktop running your application ?

Comment: How many characters do you have in the value? 50?

Comment: @Olivier. Yes, it contains 50 characters, and when a special character (Ñ) is incorrectly coded as two characters then the result are 51 characters received and FireDAC raises an exception.

Comment: It looks like a bug in FireDAC.

Comment: @Olivier, yes it looks like it should have all the information to transcode those strings itslef, as the SQL Server Management Studio does. But I'm using the latest version of Delphi & FireDAC, so this problem must have existed for a long time, I was hoping there is a workaround or a configuration to indicate FireDAC how to deal with the different codepages.

Comment: Not many people set their Windows code page to UTF-8. As for the workaround: declare the field size greater than 50.

Comment: Have you used FireDac to query the metadata for the table, and if so what size does FireDac say the server is reporting the field as?  If you haven't done that then do so, and declare your field sizee to be the same size as FireDac is reporting it to be.  Then make sure you interpret the data coming back as UTF8 data (which stores characters in varying length bytes, so the fact that you have multiple characters isn't 'incorrect' it just means it hasn't been interpreted in the correct encoding)

Comment: @Olivier That doesn't seem an adequate workaround. I was hoping for some extra parameters at the ODBCAdvanced property to tell the driver to do the proper transcode. But oversizing my fields is a lot of work (the application has more than 100 forms with datasets that would need to be changed) and would led to new problems. First I would still retrieve some special characters in their unicode codes instead of iso8859-1, and second, if I change a persistent field from String[50] to String[55] it's going to raise an exception if anyone tries now to save 55 characters on that field.

Comment: @RobLambden it reports those columns as they are : TStringFields (non-unicode) of 50 characters, It's only when I retrieve data that it fails if it contains special characters (Variable length column [nom] overflow). If I try to change the persistent fields to unicode (TWideStringFields) then it raises another exception (type mismatch for field 'nom', expecting WideString actual: String).

Comment: @MarcGuillot - TStringFields is not returned by querying the MetaData with TFDMetaInfoQuery (see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Metadata_Structure_(FireDAC) ) but I appreciate that you may have interpreted the results.  You also mention ODBCAdvanced property - I suggest using the MSSQL driver and not ODBC as the ODBC driver is much more generalised.  Also this wiki doc may be helpful (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Unicode_Support_(FireDAC) )

Comment: @RobLambden The ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server is the current client for SQL Server, but I have also tried the deprecated SQL Server Native Client 11, with the same results. :-(

Comment: @MarcGuillot - what I mean is choose the MSSQL driver in FireDAC, not the ODBC driver.

Comment: @RobLambden Sorry, I didn't understand you. Yes, I'm using the MSSQL driver. The ODBCAdvanced property is one of the Params that this driver creates.

Answer (score 0):

Just UNCHECK the option on the screen below:

[image: Windows configuration]